# Hidden status bar in IE8 becomes visible when the webpage is minimized and maximized again

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

When I open a webpage through window.open  and staus is set as no, the webpage comes wtih no status bar as expected. But when I minimize this webpage and open another web page that is having status bar enabled and again maximize my web page that had status bar disabled, what happen is my webpage now has status bar on it.

Why/how does the status bar reappear on my webpage after I minimize, render other webpage, and maximize my webpage back again?

Comment: it's IE... and it's IE8 for that matter...

Comment: Did you found the answer for this???? even we are facing the same problem..